# When using GDB, how do you see which C (not Assembly) instruction that GDB has stopped upon?

Tags: c, gdb

See, the problem is that I'm supposed to use an executable driver program (vdriver) to test the C source file I wrote (myfile.c) containing a collection of methods the driver program will use. I used gcc to compile them together (and also any files they depend on) and then ran "gdb vdriver"

Apparently, I am getting a segfault somewhere in myfile.c. The "dissasemble"-produced assembly code can even display the whole method in assembly and point to which instruction just segfaulted.

However, due to the complexity (and length) of the assembly code, I think it would be much more effective to view this line where the segfault occurred in C.

However, running the command "list *$eip" results in:

```
    No source file for address 0x804a3d3
```

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile with debugging info.

```
gcc -ggdb -c source.c -o source.o ...
```

**Update:** It looks like you're having trouble invoking GCC as well.  I suggest writing a Makefile, and taking a quick look through the GCC manual for what `-c` and `-o` mean.

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -ggdb -Wall # or whatever flags you want, read the manual

# List all files, with *.c changed to *.o (Make will figure the rest out)
my_app : file1.o file2.o file3.o file4.o
        $(CC) -o my_app $^
# The above line should start with a tab, not spaces

clean :
        rm -f my_app *.o

# List dependencies like this (technically optional)
# But if you don't do it, "make" might not re-make things that need it
file1.o : file1.c header.h header2.h
file2.o : file2.c header.h
```

Comment: Dietrich, I did exactly this, but it still gives me the same error when setting a breakpoint and then trying to see the line of C with "list"...

Comment: Could you explain more what the "-ggdb" was supposed to do?

Comment: I believe `-ggdb` is the same as `-g` on most systems; `-g` is what people are used to..

Comment: @R..: I have run on a number of systems in the past that provided inadequate debugging symbols with `-g`.  In any case, if you are using gdb, it does not hurt to use `-ggb`.

Comment: @JacobHayden: `-ggdb` adds debugging info to your program.  Without that info, GDB has no way of figuring out what lines of code each instruction correspond to.  Could you post the exact command you use for compilation?  Or try running a backtrace with the "backtrace" command?

Comment: Okay! This is what I did: gcc -ggdb -c vdriver.c myfile.c myfile_depends_on_this.c otherfiles.c

Comment: @JacobHayden: That command will create *.o object files but it will not produce an executable.  The second step is to link the object files into an executable.  You can do that with `gcc -o exename source.o source2.o ...`

Comment: Ok so at this point, I have done so far: "gcc -ggdb -c vdriver.c myfile.c myfile_depends_on_this.c otherfiles.c" and then "gcc -o vdriver vdriver.o myfile.o myfile_depends_on_this.o otherfiles.o" and then proceed to run "gdb vdriver"

Comment: Ran it and let it seg fault, then typed the command "list *$eip" and got the same error (No source file for address...)

Comment: It could have something to do with not having compiled/linked the header files associated with some of the files?

Comment: @JacobHayden: I've expanded the answer.