# GDB: What to do when you type "list" to see the code in C, but it prints to you "No source file for address __________"

Tags: c, gdb

I'll try to simplify and make clear my other question here. I am basically trying to use gdb to see where myfile.c is segfaulting. However, I cannot directly examine myfile.c under gdb, but there I am given a driver program (vdriver) that will randomly test the methods I have provided for it in myfile.c

So, after compiling with "gcc -ggdb -c vdriver.c myfile.c myfile_depends_on_this.c" I run "gdb vdriver" until it segfaults. At that point, typing "list *$eip" just prints "No source file for address 0x804something"

I am also confused about how I should "gcc -ggdb -c etc,etc" for header files such as myfile.h and myfile_depends_on_this.h, because I'm not sure whether (or how) it should be included in the command or not.

But anyway, is there any way of fixing the "No source file for address" problem?

Comment: Please show the exact command you used to build your code, and your entire GDB session.

Comment: Also, please edit your previous question with new information, instead of opening a brand-new one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When using GDB, how do you see which C (not Assembly) instruction that GDB has stopped upon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830226/when-using-gdb-how-do-you-see-which-c-not-assembly-instruction-that-gdb-has-s)

Comment: Try issuing the `bt` command. However, this usually means your code have trashed up the stack so badly that not even gdb is able to figure out anything. The quickest way to fiire out this is in my experience to use valgrind and/or a thorough code review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I understand your question (it's not quite clear to me):

1. how to debug after a segfault?
2. how to compile .h files?

As to

1. After crashes, you will no longer be in execution context and so no longer be able to use the regular debugging commands. Instead,  gcc will produce a core file. You probably need to allocate space for a core file first, then debug, as described in (eg):

   http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_38.html
2. .h files are not included in the list of files to be compiled. They are referenced from within your .c file with the usual #include  (or #include "file.h") semantic

If this wasn't your question, kindly elaborate.